# How to check value of number in Handlbars in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm running a node.js server where I use Handlebars as view engine (hbs).
I need to style positive, negative and neutral numbers in my view but I cant figure out how to do it correctly with Handlebars. I have tried with register a helper for if condition, but dont see how to use it.

Anyhow, I basically have one value: `entry.change` which is going to be either negative, positive or neutral value (-X, +X, 0).

And based on that property I would like to render different span elements, such as `<span class="negative">-X</span>` etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getNumberClass', function(number) {
  if (number > 0) {
    return 'positive'
  } else if (number === 0) {
    return 'neutral'
  } else {
    return 'negative'
  }
});
```

And usage:

```
<span class="{{getNumberClass entry.change}}">{{entry.change}}</span>
```